# google maps url usage and google api

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am pretty new to `google maps`. In my `commercial` project application i need to write a module which would generate and open `google maps url` with planned route for drivers. I've read a lot that i need `google api`, nevertheless just few minutes ago i found this official page: [google developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide)

**Google claims there**: `"You don't need a Google API key to use Maps URLs."`.

Does it mean when my `commercial app` will be generating `routes urls` which would open either `google map application` (for instance on android) or if there is no `google map` installed on device - then it will open webbrowser accordingly, does it mean in this case that this is fuly legit and no google api key is required?

Comment: The link says you can use URLs instead of API.   A URL is through a Browser manually and not through programming like c#.

Comment: @jdweng I don't think so. This is "Developer Guide". Since developer guide means for coding. Other leading sentence: "As a developer of an Android app, an iOS app, or a website, you can construct a common URL...". To me that means what it says - I could develop C# app and android app which would generate URL let's say based on some database table lang&long and display it either in google map app (android) and in C# in webbrowser control for instance. That's my understanding

Comment: I agree with you.  It depends if you consider using ASP.NET creating a webpage and doing a query through a URL programming.   You can do a query through a URL without a key, not by calling a method.

Comment: The conclusion is that, if my commercial application's code will be generating google urls with planned route in either C# asp.net/win forms/android (whatever) it is legit and doesn't require any google api - as google maps as free. Would be nice someone else to confirm.

Comment: The conclusion is that, if my commercial application's code will be generating google urls with planned route in either C# asp.net/win forms/android (whatever) it is legit and doesn't require any google api according to the link i provided. There is also no "For development only" message when using url generated by application that would also prove that. Anyway would be nice someone else to confirm.

Comment: Long time ago I was writing a number of applications that were doing web scrapping.  I was using google without any issues.  Then the applications stopped working because of upgrades that limited searches from c# using URLs.  So I'm not 100% sure to believe the link.  Not sure if google made changes to now allow URL searches.  The best way is to do your own testing.

Comment: @jdweng First of all this link comming from official google site.. Besides when i tested e.g: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={origin}&destination={destination}&waypoints={torun}|{lodz}&travelmode={travelMode}&dir_action=navigate this works and not yelling like " for development purposes" or whatsoever

Comment: Is there anyone whom could conirm out there?

Comment: If it is working for you, why do you need someone to confirm it?

Comment: @ecg8 just wanted to know either if what i am saying is true, is there any other document besides link i shared proving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct, as per the official documentation `You don't need a Google API key to use Maps URLs.`. Maps URLs can be used to build a cross-platform URL to launch the Google Maps application and perform searches, get directions, display map views or panoramic images.

Maps URLs are different from the [Google Maps Platform APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#whatis) itself which requires an API key to work. [API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#what-are-api-keys) are required to keep track of your Google Maps API intended usage.

This is an official documentation from Google, therefore, should be credible.

Comment: So what is the sense Google map platform API since maps URl usage is fully free? P. S what about markers are they free too?